# jQuery word and character count (both Chinese and English)

Tags: jquery

How can I set the word limit to 200 and not allow input and show a warning next to the text area when the limit is reached using jQuery? The user may input Chinese or English characters.

Are Chinese and English counted in the same way?

I just used the build in function set the length[1,200]

Comment: Post what you had tried.

Comment: A comma as a thousands separator in an integer value?

Comment: the range is 1 to 200 [1,200]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Chinese will work or not, but you might do this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="input" />
<span></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="input"]').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 10){
            $('span').html('You can\'t type more than 10 characters!');
        }else{
            $('span').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

See the [result here](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/xLZAv/) (just change `10` to `200`).

Answer (score 0):

It says something related to Chinese but doesn't work Chinese limit for me.

[jQuery Text Counter Plugin](https://github.com/ractoon/jQuery-Text-Counter)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer.
idea is from [This GitHub Repo](https://github.com/patw0929/jquery.chineselengthlimit)
Chinese and English aren't counted in the same way,if you count it by byteLength , you will find that chinese is 2 times of english 
you can try code below .

```
/*useByteLength
function checkTextLength($element) {
  txtCount = $element.val().replace(/[^\x00-\xff]/g, "pp").length + 
  ($element.val().match(/\n/g) || []).length;
  return txtCount;
}
```

if your condition need to count  Chinese and English  in the same way , you can try this.

```
 /*count Chinese and English  in the same way
 function checkTextLength($element) {
  txtCount = $elements.val().length + ($elements.val().match(/\n/g) || []).length;
  return txtCount; 
}
```